# GTX 1660 Ti vs. RTX 2060 for a deep learning pc

Tags: deep-learning, gpu

I'm planning to build a PC for Deep Learning, after the launch of AMD Ryzen 3rd gen processors. My budget will allow me to choose between a GTX 1660 Ti and RTX 2060. I'm tabulating the specs of both the cards below.

```
╔════════════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║      GPU       ║ GTX-1660Ti ║ RTX-2060 ║
╠════════════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║ GPU-cores      ║ 1536       ║ 1920     ║
║ Tensor-cores   ║ N/A        ║ 240      ║
║ RT-cores       ║ N/A        ║ 30       ║
║ Texture-units  ║ 120        ║ 120      ║
║ Render-outputs ║ 48         ║ 48       ║
║ Base-clock     ║ 1500       ║ 1365     ║
║ Boost-clock    ║ 1770       ║ 1680     ║
║ Mem-bus-width  ║ 192-bit    ║ 192-bit  ║
║ Mem-bandwidth  ║ 288GB/s    ║ 336GB/s  ║
║ Mem-capacity   ║ 6GB        ║ 6GB      ║
║ TDP            ║ 120W       ║ 160W     ║
╚════════════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

Given this comparison, I'd like to know which one would be a better choice for me. Would the RTX-2060 be worth the extra 70$ for the supposedly better performance? I had an initial look at the usefulness of tensor cores in Deep Learning applications, and found out the following article snippet from Nvidia website.

> **Note About Tensor Cores**
>
> Designed specifically for deep learning, Tensor Cores on newer GPUs
>   such as Tesla V100 and Titan V, deliver significantly higher training
>   and inference performance compared to full precision (FP32) training.
>   Each Tensor Core provides matrix multiply in half precision (FP16),
>   and accumulating results in full precision (FP32). This key capability
>   enables Volta to deliver 3X performance speedups in training and
>   inference over the previous generation. All samples are optimized to
>   take advantage of Tensor Cores and have been tested for accuracy and
>   convergence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would have gone with the RTX.
If I was to design deep learning models,I would be prefer more number of cores in the GPU , where RTX is the winner.

Lets not forget the Tensor cores which are present in RTX , which makes it stand out for Deep Learning processing. (Faster Tensor operations).

Go with RTX if you can afford it.